# Why a GAN trained on same data and same parameters may produce different results?

Tags: gan, generative-models

I am trying to train a Generative Adversarial Network and ran the training a few times with same dataset and same parameters but it seems tp produce different results. Why this may happen?

Answer (score 2):

The loss function error surfaces of both discriminator and generator are complex. There are many different optima on both surfaces that can yield usable solutions. There is a element of randomness where on the loss function error surfaces a training run with stop.